# BIGQUERY: IF table exists start query SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-bigquery

I want to execute my SQL command, if a certain table "t1" exists in the the dataset "d".

I tried:

IF (EXISTS (Select *
From  d.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_Schema like 't1*'))
Then
**---DO Stuff----
Else Stop query and repeat in 1 hour;**

The last part doesnt work. **Syntax error: Expected ";" but got keyword END.**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please share the complete query? Seems like we are missing pretty much the important info here. Plus, if you want to check whether table "t1" exists in the dataset, you should be doing WHERE table_name LIKE "t1%"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.